# How to find the first business date of a week in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime

We can use [`fbusdate`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/finance/fbusdate.html) to get the first business day of a *month*:

```
Date = fbusdate(Year, Month);
```

However, how do we get the first business day of a *week*?

As an example, during the week that I'm posting this, Monday 09/07/2017 was a holiday in the US:

```
isbusday(736942) % = 0
```

How do I determine that the first business day for this week would be the next day `736943`?

Comment: Monday is always the first business day of a week

Comment: Incorrect. As sometimes it is a holiday (eg in states). This week good example 09/04/2017 was a business holiday.

Comment: If you want the second week, get the first week and then add 7?

Comment: No not second week. The first business day of a week that we are in. E.g. for this week to return 736943 (Tuesday 09/05)

Comment: @JohnAndrews fair. Out of curiosity, how does it handles holydays?  I worked Monday this week because it was not holiday where I live. Is it only US? There are more countries in the world XD

Comment: Good question, I suspect there must be some country option in the specs.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Matlab determines by default the holidays with the [`holidays`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/finance/holidays.html#bvaal9c-4) function, which returns all holidays and special nontrading days for the New York Stock Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Here is a function that is based on the answer of @m7913d:

```
function Busday = fbusdateweek(date)
% Return the first business day after Sunday
% 'date' is a datenum input

dperiod  = date-6:date;
sundays  = weekday(dperiod)==1;

sunday = find(sundays==1,1,'first');
datesunday = dperiod(sunday);

% -->
Busday = busdate(datesunday);

end
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a builtin function that returns the first working day of a week, but you can obtain it by requesting [the next working day](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/finance/busdate.html) after Sunday:

```
busdate(736941); % 736941 = Sunday 09/03/2017
```

Comment: Good idea. Have written a function as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your desired `fbusdateweek` function can be done in one line using just the function [`weekday`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weekday.html) to get the first Sunday of the week then [`busdate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/busdate.html) to get the next business day after that:

```
dn = 736942;  % Date number for any day in a week
Date = busdate(dn-weekday(dn)+1);
```

**Note:** `busdate` uses the function [`holidays`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/holidays.html) by default to get all holidays and special nontrading days for the New York Stock Exchange. If necessary, you can define [an alternate set of holidays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/busdate.html#inputarg_Holiday) for `busdate` to use as follows:

```
holidayArray = ...;  % Some set of date numbers, vectors, or datetimes
Date = busdate(dn-weekday(dn)+1, 1, holidayArray);
```

This way you can define a set of localized holidays.

Comment: Cool! Is it also quicker I wonder? Conversion to datetime can take some time I remember.

Comment: @JohnAndrews: Never mind. A datetime wasn't even needed. It was *waaay* simpler. :)

Comment: ... Genius haha :)

Comment: How do you get the last? Struggling a bit

Comment: @JohnAndrews: If you want to get the last business date of the week, this should work: `Date = busdate(dn-weekday(dn)+7, -1);`